# How is the time saved calculated if you do an overpayment on a mortgage to reduce the term?

Tags: mortgage, amortization

I would like to know the equation to work out how much money is saved if you make an overpayment on a mortgage to reduce the term.

There is a promotional rate for the interest, and a standard variable rate.

I worked it out wrongly by trying:

```
aux = (1+MonthlyPromotionalRate)^NumberOfInstallements;
aux2 = aux -OverPayment*(aux-1)/Loan;
NumberOfPaymentsSaved = log(base:aux2) (1+MonthlyStandardVariableRate);
```

Comment: I used a spreadsheet that showed the whole payment schedule.  One of the columns used in the calculation was Extra Monthly Payment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with the standard loan equation based on the loan amount `s` equalling the sum of the periodic repayments `d` all discounted to present value.

```
s = principal
r = periodic rate
n = number of payments
d = payment amount
```

[image: loan equation]

Formulae for `s`, `d` & `n` are:-

```
  s = (d - d (r + 1)^-n)/r
∴ d = r s/(1 - (1 + r)^-n)
& n = - log(1 - (r s)/d)/log(1 + r)
```

Adding some example values: a 100k loan at 5% over 20 years

```
  s = 100000
  r = 0.05/12
  n = 20*12 = 240

∴ d = r s/(1 - (1 + r)^-n) = 659.96 per month
& n = - log(1 - (r s)/d)/log(1 + r) = 240 months
```

**If there is an overpayment in month 100 . . .**

The balance in month 100 can be found

```
  x = 100
  b = (d + (1 + r)^x (r s - d))/r = 69895.36
```

Without an overpayment this balance could be considered as a separate loan for `b` over the remaining 140 month term, and the repayment amount would work out the same, i.e.

```
  s = b = 69895.36
  r = 0.05/12
  n = 20*12 - 100

∴ d = r s/(1 - (1 + r)^-n) = 659.96 per month
& n = - log(1 - (r s)/d)/log(1 + r) = 140 months
```

That is all as expected.

If a *further* 5000 is paid at the end of month 100 and the previous repayment amount continues to be paid . . .

```
  s = b - 5000 = 64895.36
  r = 0.05/12
  d = 659.96

∴ n = - log(1 - (r s)/d)/log(1 + r) = 126.782 months
```

To deal with the fractional month, find the balance in month 126

```
  x = 126
  b = (d + (1 + r)^x (r s - d))/r = 513.874
```

add interest for the final balance in month 127

```
  b*(1 + r) = 516.01
```

So with a 5000 overpayment in month 100 the original loan is repaid in month **227** with a final repayment of 516.01

Without overpayment the total paid is `240 d = 158389.38`

With overpayment the total paid is `226 d + 516.01 = 149666.01`

so the overpayment saves `8723.37` and completes the loan 13 months earlier.

Comment: I tend to just say "ok, re-amortize from this point based on the new payment amount (or, for a single payment, new balance) and see how that compares to the previous result" rather than trying to directly compute the effect. Haven't checked your math but it looks reasonable as a closed-form solution.